# How to make Popcorn.js work with Video.js on iPad

Tags: mediaelement.js, video.js, popcornjs

I can't use the native video player on the iPad because it steals all touch events and I need show interactive elements over the video. Using [Video.js](http://videojs.com/) works for this purpose but, strangely, it stops [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) events from firing on iPad.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely a solution but I found that [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) is a good replacement for Video.js and plays nicely with Popcorn.

Comment: Can I see a sample of your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a specific video library. It is when you have your controls enabled for video player you cannot do any interactivity on any HTML element on top of video.

I had the same problem and i solved it by doing

```
p.controls(false); //where p is the object of popcorn js player
```

I did that when displaying any interactive element such as BUTTON on top of video and when my button was no longer needed on top of video i enabled the controls again.

```
p.controls(true);
```

And it worked like a charm!